# Do you know of a table layout module for XNA?

Tags: user-interface, layout, xna

I've just started doing some XNA stuff.  In my screens (e.g. title screen and high score screen) I find myself more and more modifying rectangles, then drawing something, then modifying another rectangle, then drawing something... repeat multiple times.

What I'd like is a table.  I'd like to specify: the amount of rows and columns, the spacing and padding, the size of the cells in pixels or percentages, and which cells are merged.  e.g.

```
var t = new TableLayout(viewPortBounds);
t.Columns=3;
t.Rows=5;
t.Padding=5;
t.Spacing=25;
t.SetRowSize(0, new Percent( 5) );
t.SetRowSize(1, 100);
```

This'd create a 3x5 table with padding and spacing.
I can then get rectangles like:

```
Rectangle r = t.Cell(1,0)
drawText(@"the title", r);
drawText(@"something else", t.Cell(0,1) ) ;
```

etc.

I'd also like the ability to merge cell, e.g. given the first row above, I'd like to merge all the cells, then when I ask for cell(0,0), I'd get a rectangle of the full width of the table (minus the spacing).

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found a couple of alternatives that follow the WPF/Silverlight paradigm.

[Red Badger's XPF](http://red-badger.com/Blog/post/XPF-Getting-Started.aspx) and Valentin's [XnamlComponent](http://msmvps.com/blogs/valentin/pages/xnaml-component.aspx).  Both look very good.  Red Badger haven't yet finalised the license but assure us that it'll be free to use for non-commercial or open-source projects.  Valentin doesn't yet mention licensing and is looking for testers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a GUI library like [Neoforce](http://www.tomshane.cz/neoforce/Features/tabid/55/Default.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I took a look at Neoforce.  Whilst it looks good it's more focused on controls rather than layout (I have my own 'controls', I just needed something to help arrange them).